# MySQL & PHP - Inserting values Error

Tags: php, mysql

When i try to insert data to my MySQL it results in error:

> "Connected successfully Error: INSERT INTO login ('nick, pass') VALUES
>   (', ') You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''nick, pass') VALUES (', ')' at line 1"

```
 <?php
    $servername = "mysql1.000webhost.com";
    $username = "a5287585_login";
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "a5287585_login";
    $nickname = $_POST['nick'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    // Vytvorenie pripojenia - Creating connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully ";

    // Vloženie dát (Nick,ecc..) - Data inserting
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login (nick, pass)
            VALUES ('$nick, $pass')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

[My MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vbHB.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Plus, that could also have been a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them because that's what's also going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO login (nick, pass) VALUES ('$nick, $pass')";
```

It should be

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO login (nick, pass) VALUES ('$nickname', '$pass')";
                                                        ^     ^// saperate quotes for both the values
```

Comment: And $nick needs to be $nickname

Comment: @KiwiJuicer Thanks buddy:)

Comment: But it still doesn´t solve my problem. The worse thing is that i saw all questions about my problem but i can´t find it..

Comment: what error you r getting now??

Comment: Same think. 
"Connected successfully Error: INSERT INTO login (nick, pass) VALUES (', ')
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: what is your table structure??

Comment: use `$nickname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['nick']);`

Comment: @Jediah If you're still getting that error, you didn't save the changes to the server. The answer shows that you should have 4 quotes in the query, you still only have 2.